# Uploading with PyMongo in a While True loop using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing

I have a script that reads data via the serial port from a development board. I want to have this script upload the data to a MongoDB collection at the end of each loop, but I don't want the loop to block because of the upload. When I try to use the multiprocessing library to do so, the loop only uploads a blank document.

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client['CompostMonitor-1']

def upload_to_database(data):
    # Connect to the collection where the data will be stored
    collection = db.RedBoard

    # Insert the data into the collection
    collection.insert_one(data)


port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
filename = '~/TestData'
containernumber = 1
baud_rate = 9600
RBSerial = serial.Serial(port, baud_rate, timeout=1)
directoryBase = "{}/{}/Bucket {}/RB".format(filename, time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"), containernumber)
pathlib.Path(directoryBase).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
logFileRB = '{}/RB_Bucket_{}_{}_{}_log.bin'.format(directoryBase, containernumber, time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"),
                                                   time.strftime("%H;%M;%S"))
csvRB = '{}/RB_Bucket_{}_{}_{}.csv'.format(directoryBase, containernumber, time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"),
                                           time.strftime("%H;%M;%S"))

startup = True

count = 0
bytearray = []
RB_DataList = []
RB_DataDict = {}

header = ['Date/Time',
          'SGP TVOC (ppb)',
          'BME Humidity (%)',
          'BME Pressure (Pa)',
          'BME Temp (Deg C)']

startTime = time.time()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=upload_to_database, args=(RB_DataDict,))

while 1:
    RB_DataDict = {'_id': ''}
    RB_inbyte = RBSerial.read(size=1)
    with open(logFileRB, 'ab') as l:
        l.write(RB_inbyte)
    bytearray.append(RB_inbyte)
    if RB_inbyte == b'\n':
        bytearray.pop()
        with open(csvRB, 'a', newline = '') as table:
            writer = csv.writer(table)
            if count == 0:
                writer.writerow(header)
            RB_DataSplit = ''.join(str(bytearray)).replace(" ", "").replace('b', '').replace("'", '').replace(",", '').\
                replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(';')
            RB_DataList.append(time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
            for i in range(len(RB_DataSplit)):
                RB_DataList.append(RB_DataSplit[i])
            print(RB_DataList)
            writer.writerow(RB_DataList)
            RB_DataDict = {'Date_Time': RB_DataList[0], 'TVOC Con': RB_DataList[1], 'BME Humidity': RB_DataList[2],
                           'BME Pressure': RB_DataList[3], 'BME Temp': RB_DataList[4]}
            print(RB_DataDict)
            RB_DataList = []
            # upload_to_database(RB_DataDict)
            if startup:
                p.start()
                startup = False

        bytearray = []
```

However, if I just call `upload_to_database(RB_DataDict)` as in the commented line, it works as intended. I *thought* that starting the process would have it continually upload RB_DataDict to my Mongo database, but it appears that it just runs one time and then stops.

I haven't found any examples of code attempting to use multiprocessing in an infinite loop, so it's hard to compare my code to something that works. How can I change this code so that it uploads RB_DataDict with the multiprocessing object each time the dictionary is populated?

Comment: It's not clear to me that the multiprocessing module is the best fit for this use case. I get the "do not block!" requirement, that's fine. But come on, it's only a 9.6 data rate. Write the contents to a file, fsync() or close() it, and move on to continue reading from the serial port. Have a single background daemon stat()'ing the append-only log file and storing fresh data in Mongo, or have the daemon look for new uniquely-named timestamped files and store them in Mongo. Oh, I see you already have unique filenames. Piece of cake. Daemon keeps looking for new ones. Done.

Comment: @J_H, thanks for the response. Just to make sure I'm understanding your suggestion, you would just get rid of multiprocessing and add code to this script (or have another separate script) that will constantly scan the log file and upload changes to the database or upload each time a new log file is created?

Comment: Yes, an immortal background daemon that never dies. Well, when the foreground program exits it should send a "please die!" message. You can do lame / slow sleep() polling. Or respond to unix signals, append filenames to a manifest, use kqueue, listen on a pipe / socket, there's lots of IPC techniques for immediately waking up a consumer process when new work arrives. If you would rather that the background server exists _only_ when there's work to be done, you might find a [Celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery) worker to be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I don't really understand *why* this works so well, but it does:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if startup:
        p.start()
        startup = False
        print('Startup == False')

    else:
        # Close the process instance and start a new one!
        p.close()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target= upload_to_database, args = (RB_DataDict,))
        p.start()
        print('should have uploaded something here')
```

Just closing the original process on the second loop and starting a new one fixes the issue. I'm not sure if, *in my particular case*, the `if __name__ == '__main__'` is necessary, as this script isn't intended to be imported for anything else, but I just followed the lead of the `multiprocessing` documentation.